# Typescript filter array based on value from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

This question has been asked many times, but I can't get it working.
I have two arrays, the first one is:

```
 first= [
      {
        id:1, descrizione: "Oggetto 1", 
        codiceAzienda: "Codice 1",
        dataInserimento:"01-01-2019",
        dataAggiornamento: "01-01-2019"
      },
      {
        id:2, descrizione: "Oggetto 2", 
        codiceAzienda: "Codice 2",
        dataInserimento:"01-01-2019",
        dataAggiornamento: "01-01-2019"
      },
      {
        id:3, descrizione: "Oggetto 3", 
        codiceAzienda: "Codice 3",
        dataInserimento:"01-01-2019",
        dataAggiornamento: "01-01-2019"
      },
      {
        id:4, descrizione: "Oggetto 4", 
        codiceAzienda: "Codice 4",
        dataInserimento:"01-01-2019",
        dataAggiornamento: "01-01-2019"
      },
      {
        id:5, descrizione: "Oggetto 5", 
        codiceAzienda: "Codice 5",
        dataInserimento:"01-01-2019",
        dataAggiornamento: "01-01-2019"
      }
    ]
```

and the second one is this:

```
second = [
          {
            id:1, descrizione: "Oggetto 1"
          },
          {
            id:3, descrizione: "Oggetto 3"
          }
        ]
```

What I want to achieve is to have an array with only the objects of the first that have the id equal to one of the object of the second. So the result would be:

```
final= [
          {
            id:1, descrizione: "Oggetto 1", 
            codiceAzienda: "Codice 1",
            dataInserimento:"01-01-2019",
            dataAggiornamento: "01-01-2019"
          },
          {
            id:3, descrizione: "Oggetto 3", 
            codiceAzienda: "Codice 3",
            dataInserimento:"01-01-2019",
            dataAggiornamento: "01-01-2019"
          }
        ]
```

I've tried doing this:

```
final= first.filter(ogg => second.map(y => y.id).includes(ogg.id));
```

but as a result I have all the objects of the first array. I've also tried with `array.some()`:

```
final= first.filter(ogg => second.some(id => ogg.id == id));
```

In this case, the final array is empty.
[Example of the second case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upl8hg)

Comment: This does not seems a typescript question as there is any reference to type, is a simple JS question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
const final = first.filter(x => second.find(y => y.id === x.id))
```

You can see this working [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/typescript-filter-array-based-on-value-from-another-array-om0kd).

Comment: Hi, it's not working... It doesn't filter the objects and the final array has all the objects from the first

Comment: @Dseaster Take a look at the console tab in the example. That's the result you asked for in the question.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but it's not working if I write it in my code and I do not understand why

Comment: I'm voting this answer as correct because it's working, even though I figured out my problem was something else and so also my solutions were correct. But not recognizing your effort/time wouldn't be fair, so thank you very much.